# Removing action bar in BottomNavigation view

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, bottomnavigationview

As the title says I am not able to remove the action bar present in the bottom navigation bar.
I tried different NoAction bar themes but it won't work for some reason.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is the example
[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7LHv.jpg)

Comment: You mean you want to hide the BottomNavigationView?

Comment: @LieForBananas No no. I want to hide the action bar present above the BottomNavigationView.

Comment: Did you try `appBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);`?

Answer (score 21):

1. Change theme to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
2. Remove codes below

```java
AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notification).build();
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below code. Just copy the code and add in your styles.xml

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Not working. Somehow the theme applies to bottombar. i am using the default template given by the android studio. I tried every method, none of them are working for me.

Comment: For the default template only, I used that code to remove the actionbar. Try to use the option in File -> Invalidate caches and Restart option. It will clear the errors and give you the solution

Comment: did it. Still getting the same thing. Not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

this is work with me :

```
       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

             // add this line 
            getSupportActionBar().hide();

    ...

    }
```

Comment: You want remove action bar with items ?

Comment: No just the actionbar which is present in the bottombar actvity. [Whole action bar itself not needed.

Answer (score 1):

ActionBar is good for User Interface, but sometimes we do want to hide it. Here we will see the ways to do it.

**1. Through code:**

You can hide it in your `onCreate` method:

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)
     supportActionBar?.hide()
   }
}
```

This line `supportActionBar?.hide()` did the job. Start the app, and it works.

**2. Though the XML with theme**

First, add a new style in the `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then, open the `AndroidManifest.xml` and apply it to the activity you want to hide the action bar. Start the app, and it works.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MyActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I might be late to this post... but I believe I found the solution for anyone still wondering. Once you change your theme to a .NoActionBar you will want to comment out these lines of code in the onCreate function of your MainActivity.kt.

This still allows the bottom navigation bar to work.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    floatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab_add)
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    // val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
    //     R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_leagues, R.id.navigation_practice, R.id.navigation_profile))
    //setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it programmatically as

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: It is giving me 3 errors ie return type required, invalid method declaration, missing method body. `ActionBar bar = getActionBar(); bar.hide();` is also not working.

Comment: use bar = getSupportActionBar();

Comment: it is not working with default android studio bottom navigation template.

Comment: Have you executed the code. As Using above method will not disappear action from from your layout

Comment: Yes i did. implemented in the MainActivity. Still Shows the error says cannot resolve symbol hide.

Comment: Please send the screenshot, where you implemented it.

Comment: It might be the case you are importing a different class. Just write the simple line as:
getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: Do you want to remove whole bottom Navigation View with icons??

Comment: You have to send me the complete code so I can debug it and resolve your problem. Please email at rajgar114@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin users:

```
// Add this to your class Mainactivity

supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Code looks like this in my MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }
}
```